# Different implementaions of Apollo's Query prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, graphql, apollo

There are different ways (2 that I know of) to use the new Query and Mutation props from Apollo. However I can only implement one of them successfully.

Defining the query within the Query prop like so:

```
 <Query query={gql`
          {
            getStudies{
              studies_id
              name_studies
              lab_studies
              objective_studies
              active_studies
            }
          }
          `}>
            {({ loading, error, data }) => {
              if (loading) return <div>Fetching</div>
              if (error) return <div>Error</div>
              const studiesToRender = data.getStudies;
              return(
              <div>
                {studiesToRender.map(study => <Study key={study.studies_id} study={study}/>)}</div>    
              )
            }}
          </Query>
```

works and brings my data back from the database for rendering

But when I try to pass the query in as a preformatted object it results in a status 400 bad request error:

```
const LIST_STUDIES = gql`
  {
    ListStudies{
      getStudies {
        studies_id
        studies_name
        studies_lab
        studies_objective
        studies_active
      }
    }
  }`
....
 <Query query={LIST_STUDIES}>
            {({ loading, error, data }) => {
              if (loading) return <div>Fetching</div>
              if (error) return <div>Error</div>
              const studiesToRender = data.ListStudies.getStudies;
              return(
              <div>
                {studiesToRender.map(study => <Study key={study.studies_id} study={study}/>)}</div>    
              )
            }}
          </Query>
```

Here is the server side typeDefs and resolvers:

```
export const typeDefs = `
    type Study {
        studies_id: ID
        name_studies: String
        lab_studies: String
        objective_studies: String
        active_studies: String
    }

    type Query {
        getStudy(studies_id: ID!): Study
        getStudies: [Study]
    }
    }`;

export const resolvers = { 
    Query: {
        getStudies: () => {
            return  db.many ( 'SELECT * FROM po1dev_v0022.studies')
                // .then(data => { console.log( data); })  
                .then(data => { return data; }) 
                .catch(error => { console.log('SELECT ALL ERROR: ', error); }); 
        }
    },
};
```

I prefer the second implementation as it seems to be more flexible for mutations and passing in state values. If I've forgotten to mention anything or something needs clarification just let me know.

Cheers :)

EDIT: I'm connecting to a local postgreSQL database using the pg-promise package

Comment: Those are different queries or what? One has `ListStudies`. If it's supposed to be query name, use it like this: `gql'query ListStudies { ... }`

Comment: I have no idea what ListStudies is meant to be. I've been following this https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/2-queries-loading-links/ and I can't see why that level is added to the query definition. But removing it does not magically make things work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that those two queries are not the same, and the second one is not formatted correctly. Here is the first one:

```
{
  getStudies {
    studies_id
    name_studies
    lab_studies
    objective_studies
    active_studies
  }
}
```

And the second one:

```
{
  ListStudies {
    getStudies {
      studies_id
      studies_name
      studies_lab
      studies_objective
      studies_active
    }
  }
}
```

The second query is wrapped in an unnecessary pair of curly brackets.

GraphQL allows shorthand notation when writing a document that allows you to omit the name of the operation and the type of operation (`query`, `mutation` or `subscription`). If the type of operation is omitted, the operation is assumed to be a query. It's good practice to avoid shorthand notation in practice, and always include both the name and the type of operation. The resulting query would then look like this:

```
query SomeOperationName {
  getStudies {
    studies_id
    name_studies
    lab_studies
    objective_studies
    active_studies
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. But my question is likely not clear. Using the query definition in the first code chunk, how do I declare the function outside of <Query> as was poorly implemented in the second code chunk.

Comment: You can define a variable called `LIST_STUDIES` and pass it in just like you're doing. All of that code was perfectly fine. The problem is the actually query you're using when defining `LIST_STUDIES` is not valid (and is NOT the same query you sent when defining it within the `Query` component itself).

Comment: Oh my freaking deity....well I think I'm going to ban myself from here for a while. Thanks for being so cordial Daniel :)